# Looking for a GUI tagging component like OSX Cocoa's NSTokenField for .NET/Ruby/Java

Tags: java, windows, macos, user-interface, tagging

I'm looking for an text input box for tagging, with autocomplete and hightlighting, kinda like how Delicious.com's old tagging input box. See the "Tags" input box in the screenshot.

I know Cocoa has a native GUI component like like this called NSTokenField. I want both Windows and OSX versions for my app so I'm looking for something similar for Windows, preferably .NET, Java SWT or Ruby.

[image: Pukka screenshot]

[image: Delicious screenshot]